# What do two semicolons mean in Java for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

I was looking inside the `AtomicInteger` Class and I came across the following method:

```
/**
 * Atomically increments by one the current value.
 *
 * @return the previous value
 */
public final int getAndIncrement() {
    for (;;) {
        int current = get();
        int next = current + 1;
        if (compareAndSet(current, next))
            return current;
    }
}
```

Can someone explain what `for(;;)` means?

Comment: I'll leave this here just in case you're a visual learner. :) http://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jlif.jpg

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It is equivalent to `while(true)`.

A for-loop has three elements:

- initializer
- condition (or termination expression)
- increment expression

`for(;;)` is not setting any of them, making it an endless loop.

Reference: [The for statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: It should be noted that traditionally `for(;;)` is the canonical endless loop, particularly in C.

Comment: What is the advantage to using `for(;;)` over `while(true)`? EDIT: I was able to answer my own question with a simple Google search: no difference and they compile to the same result. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880870/java-for-vs-whiletrue

Answer (score 9):

It's the same thing as

```
while(true) {
    //do something
}
```

...just a little bit less clear.
Notice that the loop will exit if `compareAndSet(current, next)` will evaluate as `true`.

Answer (score 3):

It's just another variation of an infinite loop, just as `while(true){}` is.

Answer (score 2):

That is a for ever loop.  it is just a loop with no defined conditions to break out.

Answer (score 2):

It's an infinite loop, like `while(true)`.