# Two semicolons inside a for-loop parentheses

Tags: for-loop, parsing, syntax, language-agnostic

I'm customising a code I found over the internet (it's the [Adafruit Tweet Receipt](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Tweet-Receipt/blob/ffc41ad59bc62f8ffcfc6e29f23f2732cc4b76a5/Gutenbird.ino#L349)). I cannot understand many parts of the code but the most perplexing to me is the for-loop with two semicolons inside the parentheses

```
boolean jsonParse(int depth, byte endChar) {
  int c, i;
  boolean readName = true;

  for(;;) {  //<---------
    while(isspace(c = timedRead())); // Scan past whitespace
    if(c < 0) return false; // Timeout
    if(c == endChar) return true; // EOD

    if(c == '{') { // Object follows
      if(!jsonParse(depth + 1, '}')) return false;
      if(!depth) return true; // End of file
      if(depth == resultsDepth) { // End of object in results list
```

What does **for(;;)** mean? (It's an Arduino program so I guess it's in C).

Comment: This is an idiomatic "Forever" loop that traces its origins to the K&R book.

Comment: Looks like Java to me, not C.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two Semi Colon Java For Loop Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676992/two-semi-colon-java-for-loop-question)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
for(;;) {
}
```

functionally means

```
 while (true) {
 }
```

It will probably break the loop/ return from loop based on some condition inside the loop body.

The reason that `for(;;)` loops forever is because `for` has three parts, *each of which is optional*.  The first part initializes the loop; the second decides whether or not to continue the loop, and the third does something at the end of each iteration.  It is full form, you would typically see something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

If the first (initialization) or last (end-of-iteration) parts are missing, nothing is done in their place.  If the middle (test) part is missing, then it acts as though `true` were there in its place.  So `for(;;)` is the same as `for(;true;)`', which (as shown above) is the same as `while (true)`.

Answer (score 5):

The `for` loop has 3 components, separated by semi-colons. The first component runs before the looping starts and is commonly used to initialize a variable. The second is a condition. The condition is checked at the beginning of each iteration, and if it evaluates to true, then the code in the loop runs. The third components is executed at the end of the loop, before another iteration (starting with condition check) begins, and is often used to increment a variable.

In your case `for(;;)` means that it will loop forever since the condition is not present. The loop ends when the code `return`s or `break`s.

Answer (score 3):

Each clause of a `for` loop is optional. So when they are excluded, it still loops. `for` loops compile into `while` loops.

The end result becomes a check to initialize any variables, which concludes after nothing happening since it is empty, a check to the boolean condition in the second clause, which is not present so the loop starts, and once the loop hits the end bracket, a check to see if there is any code to run before checking the boolean condition again.

In code it looks like:

```
while(true){

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's What Wikipedia [Says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#Use_as_infinite_loops) About it

> **Use as infinite loops**
>   This C-style for-loop is commonly the source of an infinite loop since the fundamental steps of iteration are completely in the control of the programmer. In fact, when infinite loops are intended, this type of for-loop can be used (with empty expressions), such as:
>
> `for (;;)`
>      `//loop body`
>
> This style is used instead of infinite `while(1)` loops to avoid a type conversion warning in some C/C++ compilers.Some programmers prefer the more succinct `for(;;)` form over the semantically equivalent but more verbose `while (true)` form.