# What does double semicolon mean in c?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

For example:

```
void thisIsAnExample(Hello* bye, char* name, int num, in* arr, int* sum){
                 GoodBye x;;
                   x.funName = name;
                    .
                    .
                    .
```

Comment: It means someone accidentally typed an extra semicolon...

Comment: It doesn't mean anything other than that there is a null statement - probably just a typo.

Comment: but the code seems to be working fine??

Comment: Sometimes a **semicolon** is just a **semicolon**.

Comment: These first three tags led me to believe that a complicated answer was coming...

Comment: Those voting to close this as a typo miss the point of that close reason. This is not code that's broken because of a typo. Nor is it a question others are unlikely to have because they wouldn't make this same typo. Rather, this is a legitimate question about working code and why it works, despite unfamiliar syntax.

Comment: Came here because someone else made a typo. It shouldn't have been closed.

Comment: To add to the confusion a bit, it's worth mentioning that `;;` _does_ have an actual meaning when declaring a for loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113125/two-semicolons-inside-a-for-loop-parentheses
Making this comment in case anyone else comes here while looking for that for-loop syntax, because this question is right next to the other one in Google's search results.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything. It's just an extra semicolon. You can delete it (leaving a single semicolon) without any effect on your program.

Answer (score 15):

It has the meaning of an a statement followed by an empty statement.

In C each statememnt ends with `;`. So a statement with a `;` followed by one, is a statement followed by an empty statement.

Answer (score 4):

A "double semicolon" does not have any special meaning in c. The second semicolon simply terminates an empty statement. So you can simply remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a typo. Adds a null statement to your program.